# Windows Service cannot create a text file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, event-viewer

Ok so this is my code for the `OnStart` method

```
File.CreateText("test.txt");
StreamWriter write = File.AppendText("test.txt");
write.WriteLine("Hello world, the service has started");
write.Flush();
write.Close();
```

I am successfully able to install the service. However when i start i get the message that the service started and then stopped. When i check the Event Viewer it gives me this

`Service cannot be started. System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\system32\test.txt' because it is being used by another process.`

Ok what's going on here. I don't think its a permission problem as the ProcessInstaller is set to LocalSystem.

Comment: For test's sake, please try to write the file to c:\test.txt, or any other non-system non-protected directory.

Comment: well i did tried to write F:\test.txt got the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this

```
string path = @"path\test.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path)) 
{
  // Create a file to write to. 
   using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
   {
     sw.WriteLine("Hello world, the service has started");
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Its been a long time since i have done file handling and as such i forgot the role of escape sequences. You provided me a snippet of code otherwise it would have been a long struggle for me.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to use the first `File.CreateText` statement.  This creates a stream writer on the file which is not closed.

Your File.AppendText tries to create a new StreamWriter on the same file and hence you get the `File in use` error.

Also, as MSDN says your file will be created if it does not exist.

> If the file specified by path does not exist, it is created. If the file does exist, write operations to the StreamWriter append text to the file

Answer (score 4):

I think one line code is more then enough.

```
  File.AppendAllText(@"path\test.txt", "Hello world, the service has started");
```

Appends the specified string to the file, creating the file if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

you should try with the full path for the file, the windows service run in the C:\Windows\System32 folder

```
string fileName="E:\\Service\\file.txt"
File.Create(file);
```

Comment: C:\Windows\System32 ....  That is why my service didn't throw errors and the log file was 'missing' !